# guessing game in Rust 1.3.0

Tags: rust

The guessing game's problem

```
extern crate rand;

use std::io;

use std::cmp::Ordering;

use rand::Rng;



fn main() {

    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);


    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .ok()
        .expect("failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);

    match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
        Ordering::Less    => println!("Too small!"),
        Ordering::Greater => println!("Too big!"),
        Ordering::Equal   => println!("You win!"),
    }
}
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
src\main.rs:26:21: 26:35 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&collections::string::String`,
    found `&_`
(expected struct `collections::string::String`,
    found integral variable) [E0308]
src\main.rs:26     match guess.cmp(&secret_number) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: Just read [the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html) for **one more paragraph** and it's explained: *Whew! This is a big error. The core of it is that we have ‘mismatched types’.*

Answer (score 0):

User input from `stdin` is a String. While the number you got from `rand` is a `u32`. Try using `to_string` on `secret_number`.

`match guess.cmp(&secret_number.to_string())`